# Process Graph for the program clearly showing the parent and child processes execution from creation to termination

Tags: c, fork

```
pid_t pid;
printf("Begin");
if (fork() == 0) {
    printf("First if fork==0");
    if (fork() != 0) 
        printf("First if fork!=0");
}

if (fork() != 0) {   
    printf("second if fork!=0");
    if (fork() == 0) 
        printf("second if fork==0");
}

printf("End if\n");
```

I try to understand how [`fork`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) works.
Can you draw a process graph to be understandable for me and for others?
[image]

Comment: But there is no explanation with Process Graph

Comment: can you draw it? If not, why not? What specifically dont you understand about the example?

Comment: I drawed it, but im not sure it is correct or not

Comment: @Cman good, add your drawing to the question then!

Comment: You can make your life much easier by saving the result from the call to fork like this`pid_t pid = fork(); if(pid == 0) { /* Do stuff */ } if (pid != 0) { /* Do something else */ }`

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I add that i drawed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example has *four* [`fork`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)s. Typically this is done differently

```
pid_t child_pid = fork();
// both parent and child process return from `fork()` and continue here
if (child_pid == -1) {
    // still parent process, error handling
    // no child process was created
} else if (child_pid == 0) {
    // this is the child process
} else {
    // this is the parent process, child_pid > 1
}
```

Now you can clearly see, which code is run in the parent, and which one is run in the child process.

---

Back to your example, you have a main process doing the `fork`s (ignoring error handling)

```
if (fork() == 0) {
    printf("First child process\n");
    if (fork() != 0)
        printf("First child process (parent part)\n");
    /*
    else
        printf("Grandchild\n");

    // fall through for both first child and grandchild
    */
}

// Main process, and first child, and grandchild
if (fork() != 0) {
    // also first child and grandchild ("parent" part)
    printf("Main process (parent part)\n");
    if (fork() == 0)
        // also third grandchild, and second great-grandchild
        printf("Third child process\n");
}
/*
else
    // also second grandchild, and first great-grandchild
    printf("Main process, second child\n");
*/
```

This means, you have a main process, having three children. The first of the child processes does a fork too, creating a grandchild.

---

But, both the first child and the first grandchild continue with the same code to the second outer if, and so create additional children, grandchildren, and great-grandchildren.

So, in the end the main process has three children. From the first child, three grandchildren descend, of which the first grandchild has two great-grandchildren of its own.

Unless I forgot one or two or so, of course :-)

Comment: Could you check my Process graph please

Comment: You're doing `fork()` four times, so you have five processes including the main process. If the bottom line is the main process, you need to add a final/third fork after the second branch.

Comment: At first, I missed the (grand-)child continuing and forking again, so there are more than just the initial five processes. This also means, you must draw some more lines.